# extjs 3.4 getModifiedRecords after markDirty not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am using extjs 3.4 and I want to make records to appear when I use getModifiedRecords.

`dtl.store.getAt(i).markDirty();`
This is what I did and when I `console.log()` it I can see 
`dirty:true` and also
`modified:{idStyle: "TEST-4", idStyleDtl: 2052, color: 6, colorNm: "BLACK", s1: 0, …}`

It clearly shows it has been modified and there's dirty flag but when I do `ojbStore.getModifiedRecords()` it returns just empty [ ]. I don't understand why it won't return the `modified` records.. Is there any other condition I need to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So lets start with solution(click X button and look into the console): [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ha5)

Now what happens here is that i manually call my own added function in store called `markDirtyFix` and pass it a record(which i want to mark as dirty) to put it in modified-records list. Actually it is a copied function `afterEdit` from store. I just commented fireEvent of update(because this forces request to be sent on update, and you want to make it dirty "only locally"):

```
afterEdit: function(record){
    if(this.modified.indexOf(record) == -1){
        this.modified.push(record);
    }
    this.fireEvent('update', this, record, Ext.data.Record.EDIT);//removed
},
```

So the miracle happens and `store.getModifiedRecords()` returns your record in array included.

Now talk about problem. So the problem is that `markDirty()` looks like this(from official docs):

```
markDirty: function(){
    this.dirty = true;
    if(!this.modified){
        this.modified = {};
    }
    this.fields.each(function(f) {
        this.modified[f.name] = this.data[f.name];
    },this);
}
```

and here is not anything that would call `afterEdit` or something like this to make your records dirty on a store level(well as you see it becomes dirty only on a record level).
Maybe someone say it is meant to be used only on a record level but markDirty doc description says:

> Marking a record dirty causes the phantom to be returned by Ext.data.Store.getModifiedRecords ..

So it should have worked(but didn't).